# Upload image to ios server without base64 in post method with text in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, uiimageview

What i trying to do is send image and text to my database in post method

```
- (void)uploadpic
  {
     NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageview.image, 90);
//   NSString *action=@"tempinsert";

NSString *s=@"54.316130";
NSString *s2=@"9.950930";
NSString *facebook=@"12345";
NSString *cate=@"1";

NSString *action=@"insert";

NSString *note=@"Iiiiiii";


NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url.php"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\"popup1.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  parameter username

//    "lat=%@&long=%@&sdkuserid=%@&cat=%@&action=%@"]; My parameters


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"sdkuserid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[facebook dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//  parameter token
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"insert\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[action dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// parameter method
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cat\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[cate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//parameter method

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"long\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[s2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
// NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
//
NSLog(@" -------   >%@",returnData);
NSLog(@" -------   >%@",dict);
}
```

output

> take photo[1295:31484]  -------   ><0d0a0d0a 0d0a0d0a>
>
> take photo[1295:31484]  -------   >(null)

My output is always null.I am trying to send image and few text to server. Although i donnot have any such validation.The response I get is null

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: yes. I this days use AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to upload image with text using post method.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourhost.com/"]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0.5);
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"key" : @"Value"
                                 };
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"imageupload.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"userfile" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%f.jpg",[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
```